# Is it possible to measure the voltage produced in heart

Tags: voltage, multimeter, voltage-measurement, biopotential

I learnt from my high school biology that human heart will produce about 1mV from the sinoatrial node.(voltage will vary like the graph in ECG test).Is it possible to measure the voltage with any instrument which can be available in a electronics laboratory(like multi meters,voltmeters,oscilloscope etc.) which is pre-amplified using a amplifier.

Comment: You could use an oscilloscope

Comment: You'll probably need an "instrumentation amplifier" to successfully suppress noise. To get any decent measurement you'll want to use a technique known as "driven right leg" to further suppress environment noise. Be extremely cautious when connecting mains powered devices to a human body, leakage currents can get much higher (and dangerous) than you would initially expect. Best is to use battery powered equipment. It is much easier to pick up the voltages from muscles in your arms or legs because those are closer to the surface.

Comment: Even battery powered equipment is *not* automagically safe when working with low impedane ECG electrodes on the human body. Please use an ECG simulator for your experiments.

Comment: Please for the love of your religious diety of choice do not try this until you know what you're doing.

Comment: using an oscilloscope!!!Can you please tell me the way?

Comment: You won't be able to use an oscilloscope to view this signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to measure the voltage using lab equipment, and a little bit of help.

You'll want to use some type of amplifier, ideally a precision, instrumentation amplifier - these are designed with very good Common Mode Rejection (CMRR) and gain.

Once you've set up an instrumentation amplifier, all you'll need is to connect the output to your oscilloscope, so that you can see the waveform.

Here is an example circuit (taken from [here](https://www.picotech.com/library/application-note/electrocardiogram-ecg-circuit-for-use-with-oscilloscopes)) - this site also has a lot of good, further reading.

[image: EKG Amplifier]

Please, if you intend to make such a device, be very careful! Connecting the human body to any electrical device can be dangerous, and appropriate precautions should be observed!

Comment: Is there any possibility to get harmed?Because I not going to press the leads deep in the skin it.I just keep this wires on the surface of the chest which is sufficiently dry(provides much resistance).Still it harms?

Comment: It may or may not harm you, but do you really want to take the chance? On dry skin, using proper diode protection, and battery powered (not mains), you would likely be fine. Considering the consequences (possible death), why take the chance? I try to never use any device that could kill me if I had a (moderately deep) cut. An off the shelf EKG/ECG device is already certified to not hurt you under simple, completely reasonable conditions (like having a cut or sweating) - I would stick to those.

Comment: Okay ...I got the point.Then what is the circuit which is used in the ECG that doesn't supposed to harm?If I know that,there may be a possibility to develop a safer device than the diode protected one.The device,which I planned to develop is just is going to be in the voltage range (1.1 to 3.3 V) and current of maximum 20mA.( battery running)

Comment: @Aadarsh This is likely similar to the circuit used in a commercial ECG, but the actual information is likely proprietary. In most countries, there are significant regulations that have to be tested/met in order to sell safe medical equipment. I'll just add that, while 20mA isn't terribly dangerous (painful, but not deadly), if your body creates a lower resistance path, then you will draw more than 20mA from the battery (unless you have proper fusing, etc). The essence is that there are a lot of design decisions to increase safety. They are well outside the scope of this question.